# Crazy python import error

Tags: python, import, path, syntax-error

I have a python file that will not correctly perform an import.

If I go to the python prompt I can manually import the module without error.

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Feb 22 2012, 16:06:13) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp
```

When I step through the program with pdb, the result of executing the import:

```
-> from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/ralphie/Desktop/Projects/catamaran/build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/amqplib/__init__.py(0)?()
```

When I check sys.path:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Feb 22 2012, 16:06:13) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from amqplib import client_0_8 as amqp
>>> import sys  
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg',
'/usr/lib  /python2.4/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.4.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/ClientForm-0.2.10-py2.4.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/simplejson-2.3.2-py2.4-linux-i686.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/amqplib-1.0.0-py2.4.egg',
'/usr/lib/python24.zip',
'/usr/lib/python2.4',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric',
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PIL', 
'/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0']
```

It is not coming from environment variables, I've deleted all .pyo & .pyc files.

I just have no idea where that crazy egg reference is coming from.

Any clues sincerely appreciated.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: it also depends on where you opened your python prompt from..

Comment: `.egg` directories and zipfiles are typically added to `sys.path` through setuptools' insane `.pth` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading python to a more recent version, I had a lot of issues with python2.4 and amqp.

Even though the import statement succeeded the functional logic is not tested or executed until called.

Comment: Long story short.  Made directories listed in error, placed files there.  That worked for now.  Next stop will be new VM with new Python.